# nextjs Helmet or internal Head component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-helmet

I got confused to use `Helmet` or `nextjs` internal `Head` component , in one hand I have `Head` component internally without any extra overhead , in other hand we have well known `Helmet` with some other advantages.

Could some one give us a best practice about choosing which of them ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use `Head` until it no longer serves your needs. No reason to increase your build size with an extra package if it's going to do the exact same thing. Unless there's a performance boost (there's not) or `Helmet` can do something you need better than `Head` can, use `Head`.

Answer (score 0):

There are active issues which may get you in the long run with next/head last time I checked. https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3494 and https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/8220. Haven't checked react-helmet of late for similar bugs however I know I chose react-helmet because of these bugs in next/head.

Best practise is best decided by your team, what is best practise to one team may not to another :-)